# mask with inplace=True in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (`df`) with columns  "ID", "ParentID", and "gender". All the "ID"s have some "ParentID". I made a subset of the data frame which reflects children from a specific "parentID", i.e. `chi_df = df[ParentID=371]`. I want to select a smaller data frame having `gender="Female"` and I want to switch corresponding genders in the original data frame.

This is what I tried:

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({"ID":[ 2811886267,34000002329444427,2811879148,79000001554869921,2811879689],
"Parent_ID":[-1,2811880323,2811886267,2811886267,2811886267],
"gender":['BOY','GIRL','GIRL','GIRL','GIRL']
})

chi_df=df[df.Parent_ID.values==2811880323].copy()
df[df.Parent_ID.values==2811880323]["gender"].mask(chi_df.gender.values == "GIRL", "THIRD", inplace=True)
```

It just raised a warning:

```py
~/somepath/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:8870: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  return self._update_inplace(result)
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is your expected output?

Comment: I still do not understand what you're trying to do. Update your question with an explanation of what you are trying to do and what the desired output is. If you can do this using a loop and want to know a numpy way of doing it, then add the looping code to better explain the logic.

Comment: I have updated the quesion as I tried some indirect  way to ask the original problem

Comment: You show what you have tried but you have not explained why it doesn't work. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). (And that's ignoring the fact that the code you provide is not valid python code.)

Comment: Hope the picture help, I know it is giving a warning, but its not an error.

Comment: Please share code and errors as text, not pictures.

Comment: As I have already suggested, please share a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Sorry for being nieve @jared, I beleive now you will be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're trying to do but there's a number of issues with your example

- You mix `chi_df` and `df` on the last line - generally this will work if they're views onto the same dataset but it can cause hard to find bugs
- You don't need to use `df.gender.values` - this casts the column to a `numpy` array. It's not wrong but unnecessary (unless you need numpy functions)
- `df[df["Parent_ID"]==2811880323]["gender"]` returns a series not a dataframe, I'd use `df.loc[df["Parent_ID"]==2811880323]`

My guess as to what you want is:

```py
df=pd.DataFrame(
    {"ID":[ 2811886267,34000002329444427,2811879148,79000001554869921,2811879689],
    "Parent_ID":[-1,2811880323,2811886267,2811886267,2811886267],
    "gender":['BOY','GIRL','GIRL','GIRL','GIRL']
})

df2 = df.loc[df["Parent_ID"]==2811880323]
df2.mask(df2['gender'] == "GIRL", "THIRD")
```

Edit: Based on your comment below, I think you're trying to update the values of the gender column to "THIRD" based on the condition `Parent_ID==2811880323 and gender=="GIRL"` which you can do using [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) i.e.

```py
df.loc[(df['gender'] == "GIRL") & (df["Parent_ID"]==2811880323), ["gender"]] = "THIRD"
```

This select the specific rows and columns, then broadcasts the rhs ("THIRD") to match the shape of the lhs and assigns it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications @David. I want the results of your line ``` df2.mask(df2['gender'] == "GIRL", "THIRD")``` to be reflected in my original dataframe "df".  Please mind the last phrase of the question. Please see my naive solution, that is something I want in the end.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it didn't work is that I was trying to use `inplace=True` on a subset which does not refer to the original data, i.e.  `df[df.Parent_ID.values==2811880323]` is a subset of df, and when I use `chi_df.gender.values == "GIRL"`, this try to modify the content of subset(`df[df.Parent_ID.values==2811880323]`). Using `inplace=True`, on subset to get the results reflected in the original(df) dataset is wrong.

The easy way out to the solution of the problem is a simple combined equivalent indexing criteria, i.e

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({"ID":[ 2811886267,34000002329444427,2811879148,79000001554869921,2811879689],
"Parent_ID":[-1,2811880323,2811886267,2811886267,2811886267],
"gender":['BOY','GIRL','GIRL','GIRL','GIRL']
})


idxxx=(df.Parent_ID.values==2811880323) & (df.gender.values=="GIRL")
df["gender"].mask(idxxx, "THIRD", inplace=True)

However, the solution turned out to be a naive approach. But I was more inclined toward a better solution.
```